# Display a limited amount of entries in Angular

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a table in Angular and I only want to display 3 rows of it in the parent component and when you press the full table button to see the full table entries.

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <button class="btn font-weight-bold" (click)="openFullTable()">Full Table</button>
        <app-table></app-table>
        //here I want to display only 3 rows
    </div>
    ........
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are setting a variable called `showFullTable` to true within `openFullTable` method, you can use `*ngFor` this way

```
 <app-table
   *ngFor="let data of (showFullTable ? collection : (collection | slice:0:3))"
 >
 </app-table>"
```

Comment: take account slice begin with 0, not with 1, if you write slice:1:3 display the second, third and fourth elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SlicePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

```
 <li *ngFor="let i of collection | slice:1:3">{{i}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parent template:

...
    <button class="btn font-weight-bold" (click)="openFullTable()">Full Table</button>
    <app-table [isFullTable]='isFullTable'></app-table>
...



parent component:

...
  isFullTable: boolean = true;

  openFullTable() {
    this.isFullTable = !this.isFullTable;
  }
...


child component class:

...
export class Table {
    @Input() isFullTable: boolean;
}
...



child template:

<div *ngIf="isFullTable">
    <li *ngFor="let i of collection">{{i}}</li>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isFullTable">
    <li *ngFor="let i of collection | slice:0:3">{{i}}</li>
</div>
```

With your openFullTable() method, you can change the value of boolean attribute isFullTable. It should change the value in the child component and trigger the tables shown.

Comment: It just sais that " isFullTable" is undefined

Comment: sorry, it should say [isFullTable]='isFullTable'. I have corrected it.